# Comportamento inadequado ao esticar imagem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Tenho o seguinte código html:

```
<figure>
    <div id="test">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="wideStretch" src="caminhodaimagem/img1.jpg" alt="Img 1" />
        </a>
    </div>
</figure>
```

Desejando esticar a imagem sem que ela perdesse sua proporção, resolvi fazer o *stretching* dessa maneira:

```
#test a {
    position: absolute; 
}

.wideStretch {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

figure {
    max-width: 889px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
```

Contudo, a imagem só fica devidamente esticada no Internet Explorer quando mudo a propriedade `position` para a classe `wideStretch`.

Por que isso ocorre? De que modo a posição da tag `<a>` afeta `<img>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa situação acontece porque o valor padrão da propriedade `display` nos elementos `a` e `img` muda de `inline` para `block` no momento em que você aplica o `position: absolute`.

Isso, aliado ao fato de no seu código só existir o `height: 100%` no `<img>`, e não no `<a>`, faz com que a imagem só fique certa quando o `position` está no `<img>`. Quando você aplica `height: 100%` em algo, [é uma boa ideia aplicar também nos elementos superiores](http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/) (já que o fallback quando não existe uma altura definida é o `auto`).

Veja a mudança que fiz abaixo:

```
#test a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%; /* Veja que adicionei o height aqui também */
}

.wideStretch {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

figure {
    max-width: 889px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 100px auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Acho que fica mais fácil de entender removendo os `position`'s:

```
#test a {
    /* Se você comentar qualquer um dos dois (display ou height), 
       ou os dois, não vai funcionar . A imagem só fica certa quando 
       ambos estão ativados */
    display: block;
    height: 100%; 
}

.wideStretch {
    /* O height aqui também é necessário */
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

figure {
    max-width: 889px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
```

Comment: Muito bem apontado de ter que aplicar as mudanças aos elementos anteriores. Bastou fazer o mesmo para a div que continha `a` que funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado (: